# Recycler Adapter isn't working that in the fragment

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
class PostListFragment : Fragment() {
    val postList=ArrayList<Posts>()

    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerAdapter
    private lateinit var firestore:FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentPostListBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    var user_mail=""
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        binding=FragmentPostListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        user_mail= auth.currentUser?.email.toString()
        getPostSelf()

        recyclerViewAdapter= RecyclerAdapter(postList)
        
        val layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager=layoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.adapter=recyclerViewAdapter


    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_list, container, false)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun getPostSelf(){

        //Buraya Firestore dan kullanıcıya ait postları çekeceğiz.

        firestore.collection("Posts").whereEqualTo("post_mail", user_mail)
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
                if (exception != null) {

                } else {
                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {

                            var documents = snapshot.documents
                            postList.clear()

                            for (document in documents) {
                                var postObject = Posts(user_mail)
                                postObject.postLabel =document.get("post_label") as String
                                postObject.postDesc =document.get("post_desc") as String
                                postObject.postTime =document.get("post_time") as String
                                postObject.postFullName =document.get("post_FullName") as String
                                postList.add(postObject)
                            }
                            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
    }

    }
```

Recycler Adapter but I'm using this adapter class in different activity, I mean I want to use same adapter in different activity and fragment:
Can I use same adapter in different classes ? And Can I create a different recycler row for same adapter.I mean I want changeable adapter settings , more complicated adapter.

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val postlist: ArrayList<Posts>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.PostsVH>() {
    //Burada post list i postlarin id sini yazariz diye dusundum.
    class PostsVH(val itemBinding: RecyclerViewItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostsVH {
        val itemBinding= RecyclerViewItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        // Burada satir goruntusunu baglamis olduk.
        return PostsVH(itemBinding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return postlist.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostsVH, position: Int) {

        holder.itemBinding.postDetails.text= postlist[position].postDesc
        holder.itemBinding.postTime.text= postlist[position].postTime.substring(11)
        holder.itemBinding.postLabel.text= postlist[position].postLabel
    }

}
```

I want to use same adapter in different activity and fragment.Can I use I don't know.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is "yes", but that's probably not what you really wanted to know - [yes/no questions are kind of problematic here](https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#yes-no-question). Instead of asking questions whose answer is yes or no, you should make an attempt, describe what you're trying to do, show what you have so far, and explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.So What is the my issue.I can't see anything in the fragment frame.If you can help me I will be so pleasure.Thank you

Comment: "isn't working that in the fragment" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?